# Launch jnlp application

Tags: java

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 and am trying to follow the instructions here:

[IcedTea-8 cannot run any jnlp application (maybe due to openjdk-11?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134881/icedtea-8-cannot-run-any-jnlp-application-maybe-due-to-openjdk-11)

When I do

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

It says

```
--2019-08-12 22:38:17--  
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre- 
headless_8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb
Resolving mirrors.kernel.org (mirrors.kernel.org)... 198.145.21.9, 
2001:19d0:306:6:0:1994:3:14
Connecting to mirrors.kernel.org 
(mirrors.kernel.org)|198.145.21.9|:80... 
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk- 
8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb 
[following]
--2019-08-12 22:38:17--  
http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8- 
jre-headless_8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb
Resolving mirrors.edge.kernel.org (mirrors.edge.kernel.org)... 
147.75.95.133, 2604:1380:3000:1500::1
Connecting to mirrors.edge.kernel.org 
(mirrors.edge.kernel.org)|147.75.95.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-08-12 22:38:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you directly go to the link you're using with `wget`, [it shows 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOSOt.jpg), which is why you must be getting that error. The third link on that list also does not seem to be working, so maybe you should get `openjdk jre` using some other way or by running

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`