# How do I undo a series of commands that failed to work with etpro_launch.jnlp, and restore things to its prior state?

Tags: java

After trying to launch Java-based Etrade Pro (etpro_launch.jnlp) on the latest version of Ubuntu (1:18.04.11.12) using the series of commands below from [IcedTea-8 cannot run any jnlp application (maybe due to openjdk-11?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134881/icedtea-8-cannot-run-any-jnlp-application-maybe-due-to-openjdk-11/1135004#1135004?newreg=5beb81b072684e5186e91c6b5e5b8f55), and failing, I trued to undo the whole thing, but failed at that, too. What can I do to undo these commands (release the "pins") and perhaps install Java to launch Etrade Pro written in Java?  I can't seem to undo the pin/hold commands, methinks.  Thanks.

```
sudo apt purge oracle-java11-* -y
sudo apt purge *openjdk* -y
sudo apt autoremove --purge -y

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -y ./openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -y ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -y ./openjdk-8-jre_8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/icedtea-web/icedtea-netx-common_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt install -y ./icedtea-netx-common_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_all.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/icedtea-web/icedtea-netx_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -y ./icedtea-netx_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Also we need to pin/hold the versions of such packages with single long command below:

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-java8
Package: icedtea-netx
Pin: version 1.6.2-3ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: icedtea-netx-common
Pin: version 1.6.2-3ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: openjdk-8-jre
Pin: version 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: openjdk-8-jre-headless
Pin: version 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
Pin-Priority: 1337

EOF
```

Comment: Please clarify your details, you mention the latest release of Ubuntu, however I see reference to 18.04 & 16.04, so please clarify what you consider the latest means.

Comment: What's difficult to undo? You created a file, you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lock/pin file with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-java8
```

Then:

- upgrade manually installed packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- or remove them

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
  ```